# How can i set a variable from my controller to my view ? (profil edition)

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a publishing city form, I need stored in a variable the value of the status field (current city).

```
 $this->Town->id = $id; 
 $this->request->data = $this->Town->read('name,id');
```

That's what I did, unfortunately in my Cake view (by echo), he tells me that statut is an array "Array".

```
$statut=  $this->Town->read('statut'); 
$this->set(compact('statut'));
```

Comment: I don't think you are using `read()` correctly.

Comment: What's your question? How to use an array vs. a scalar value? Why you have an array as opposed to a scalar value?

Comment: Dude : `That's what I did, unfortunately in my Cake view (by echo), he tells me that statut is an array "Array".` Then use print_r to print OR use take it in variable and accesss by their index.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this error because $statut is an array.
   Write `pr($statut);` on your .ctp file.
   This will give you desired output.

else:

```
  $this->Town->id = $id; 
    $this->request->data = $this->Town->read('name,id');
    $statut=  $this->Town->read('statut'); 
    $statut = $statut[$id]
    $this->set(compact('statut'));
```

now try `echo $statut;` on your .ctp file.